# Use JavaScript for file

Tags: javascript

I want to implement this code example. When link is clicked confirmation window is displayed.

***JavaScript code:***

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
        var confirmIt = function (e) {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
        };
        for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
            elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
        }
    </script>
```

***JSP which calls the JavaScript:***

```
print.itemText( "<a href =" + entry.getKey() +" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure that you want to do this action?')\" target=”_blank”> " + entry.getKey() + "</a>");
```

The issue is that I would like to display the warning message only for links which contain the word `reset` and `cache`.

Do you know how I can edit the JavaScript code as a function and use it from a file?

Comment: What does it mean by edit? Isn't the JS file your code? Btw in the js code, is the ```confirm``` function come from the global scope ?

Comment: It's not very clear what your goal is. Your javascript and JSP seem to pursue the same goal but don't work together...

Comment: My idea is to move the JavaScript code into .js file and use it as function. Do you know how I have to edit the code?

Comment: The current code is working.....